# Error running rake task from IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rake, load-path

I am having a problem running the 'test' Rake task from IntelliJ Idea in Ruby On Rails application:

*Error running test: File 'test/unit/autorunner.rb' wasnt found in $LOAD_PATH of Ruby SDK with interpreter: '{1}'*

But the file is located at %RUBY_HOME%/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit and I have no problems when running other rake tasks.

Running MS Windows XP

Please advice.

Comment: In general you need to provide OS you are running, since RubyMine works on Linux, Mac and Windows.

I am assuming it's Windows?

Check RubyMine forums, but please provide more info.

Comment: Whats in $LOAD_PATH?  What's in %RUBY_HOME%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sorry for the answer I just noticed it's a 2 year old question ...**

i hit a similar issue with the test runner in TeamCity - I'm really not sure as I do not use RubyMine but it might be the same issue (considering they use the same code base for their products) ...

it helper when I updated the `test-unit` gem from the built in 1.x version to an explicit 2.x :

```
group :test do
  gem 'test-unit', '2.1.2'
  ...
end
```

then `bundle update` as usual, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with 2.1.9 after upgrading RubyMine from 2017.2.1 to 2017.2.4. I was able to select the proper version by going into Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems -> [my ruby version] -> scrolling down to test-unit -> and selecting the specific version and hitting [Apply].

(We don't have `test-unit` in our `Gemfile` otherwise and I was wary of applying a change to a project that was specifically for a single editor's use case.)